# Como fazer form filho alterar valores no form pai C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um cadastro em C#. Existe um botão "pesquisa rua" que abre um *form* filho de pesquisa. Ao se executar a pesquisa, apresenta o resultado no *datagrid* desse *form* filho. Gostaria que o evento `cell_click` do *datagrid* completasse a *combobox* existente no form pai.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

É possível resolver o seu problema passando a referência do pai para o filho. Imagino que você cria uma instância dessa `Form` filha dentro da `Form` pai, sendo assim, basta passar a referência da seguinte forma:

**Na `Form` pai**

```
FormFilha container = new FormFilha(this);
```

**Na `Form` filha**

```
private FormPai parent = null;
public FormFilha(FormPai _parent){
  this.parent = _parent;
}
```

A partir daí é possível controlar a Form pai de dentro da Form filha, inclusive elementos que estejam internos a `FormPai`, como o `ComboBox` por exemplo, desde que a referência para esse elemento tenha nível de encapsulamento `public`.

Comment: quando digito o `this` em `new FormFilha(this)`, recebo um erro: "Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context.".

Answer (score 8):

Nesse caso você pode passar o form pai como parâmetro para a classe, e através desse parâmetro (no caso o objeto do form pai) você pode interagir com o form pai.

Codigo do Form1:

```
public Form1()
{
       InitializeComponent();
}
    //botao que ABRE o FORM B
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 formB = new Form2(this); //this, significa que estou passando ESSA classe (instância dela) como param
    formB.Show();
}
```

Codigo do Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 instanciaDoForm1; //objeto do tipo FORM 1, que será usado dentro da classe
    //inicializador do FORM
    public Form2(Form1 frm1) //recebo por parametro um objeto do tipo FORM1
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        instanciaDoForm1 = frm1; //atribuo a instancia recebida pelo construtor a minha variavel interna
        //associo o mesmo texto do tbxTextBoxFormA ao meu FORM B
        txtTextBoxFormB.Text = instanciaDoForm1.txtTextBoxFormA.Text.ToString();
    }
    //botao alterar
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //passo para a textbox do FORM A o mesmo texto que está na minha do FORM B
        instanciaDoForm1.txtTextBoxFormA.Text = txtTextBoxFormB.Text.ToString();
        instanciaDoForm1.txtTextBoxFormA.Refresh(); //recarrego ela
    }
}
```

Assim é possível interagir com o grid da mesma forma que foi feita com o textbox.

Artigo adaptado do meu amigo Fernando Passaia
http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/1741/trocando-informacoes-entre-windows-forms-em-csharp.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Não é uma boa prática delegar essa responsabilidade para o formulário filho. Em geral seria responsabilidade do formulário pai (que contém o combobox) modificar o conteúdo deste combo. Você pode criar o formulário filho como uma fonte de dados (o trabalho dele seria listar os itens e dizer qual foi selecionado)

Ao exibir o formulário com um "ShowDialog" você recebe um enum com o resultado daquele form (OK, Cancelar, etc) e pode usar esta flag para saber se o usuário não fechou a tela sem selecionar nada.
Para obter o item selecionado você pode, através de propriedades, expor o conteúdo do form filho. Isso permite que esse formulário filho seja utilizado por qualquer formulário pai.

```
public class Cidade
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}

public partial class FormPai : Form
{
    private void btnObterCidade_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var seletorCidade = new SeletorCidade();
        var resultadoSeletor = seletorCidade.ShowDialog();

        if (resultadoSeletor == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var cidadeSelecionada = seletorCidade.CidadeSelecionada;
            comboCidade.SelectedItem = cidadeSelecionada;
        }
    }
}

public partial class SeletorCidade : Form
{
    public Cidade CidadeSelecionada { get; set; }

    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }

    private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Uma boa maneira de fazer isso em C# é criar um evento no Form filho.
Por exemplo:

```
public event Action<String> EnderecoSelecionado;
```

Quando você criar o Form filho no Form pai, você se registra neste evento:

```
formFilho.EnderecoSelecionado += enderecoSelecionado_event;
```

Quando o usuário clicar no grid do Form filho, você verifica se existe funções registradas no evento, se houver você o executa:

```
if( EnderecoSelecionado != null ) {
    EnderecoSelecionado( o_endereco_selecionado );
}
```

Desta forma a interface entre Pai e Filho ficará bem explicita e o mesmo evento pode ser reaproveitado em outras partes da sua aplicação.
Este é uma expressão idiomatica comum do C# e poucas vezes me arrempedi de usa-la.

Answer (score 5):

O jeito mais fácil de fazer isso é criar uma variável publica no FormFilho e usar o ShowDialog() para chamaer ele com o DialogResult, assim, quando clicar no datagrid vc chama este código:

Declaração no formFilho

```
public int codigo { get; set; }
```

Comando do click

```
codigo = valor;
DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

Chamada do formFilho no FormPai

```
Form2 formFilho = new Form2();
if (formFilho.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
     comboBox1.SelectedValue = formFilho.codigo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pra mim funcionou assim.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // no meu caso quis pegar um Objeto do form filho.
    private Cliente cliente = null;
    public Cliente Cliente {
        get { return cliente; }
        set { cliente = value; }
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 filho = new Form2();
        filho.Pai = this;
        filho.Show();
        Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Agora no Form filho.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Form1 pai = null;
    public Form1 Pai {
        get { return pai; }
        set { pai = value }
    }

    private void Button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cliente cliente = new Cliente(long.parse(textBox1.Text));
        pai.Cliente = cliente;
        pai.Visible = true;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

desta forma eu chamo o filho, passo o pai para um atributo dentro do filho e retorno um objeto para o form pai.

tentei de outras formas porém no meu Visual Studio 2017 essas outras formas estavam iniciando um Form vazio que não era o que eu estava iniciando.

e na hora de passar o Objeto do Filho para o pai, estava dando um erro de estância nula(null).

espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer via Eventos / delegados [a qual acho mais robusto], retorno de valores com variável estática em classe terceira, passagem do formulário via argumento para alteração de propriedades e, também há uma possibilidade que ninguém cita - acho que é a mais complicada - você PODE acessar a informação diretamente através da lista de formulários abertos [Application.OpenForms], encontrá-lo e alterar a propriedade.

O Ponto negativo é, se você mudar o nome do controle ou formulário, terá que alterá-lo também no código, tornando mais complicado a manutenção.

Fiz um projeto de exemplo para ficar mais simples o entendimento:

1. frmMain - formulário Pai
2. frmSearch - form pesquisa
3. No frmMain, crio um TextBox, com nome txtEx
4. Chamo o formulário Pesquisa frmSearch . Aberto o frmSearch , chamo o clique de botão e nele Tento alterar o controle pai:

**Exemplo:**

```
// Inicio
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox myText = (TextBox)Application.OpenForms["frmMain"].Controls["txtEx"];

        myText.Text = "10";

        this.Dispose();
    }
```

**Pronto, quando retorno ao formulário frmMain, o valor "10" está escrito no TextBox.**
Tenha cuidado, se você errar o nome do formulário ou do controle, irá se deparar com o lançamento de um System.NullReferenceException. Trate este código.

**Uso:**

```
// Acesse: Application.OpenForms["NomeDoFormulário"]  e Controls["NomeDoControle"]
// Declara um controle TextBox, que servirá de ponteiro para o seu controle no formulário pai
// Faz a Conversão explícita de tipo de Controle (para poder alterar as propriedades) [(TextBox) ObjetoXYZ]
TextBox myText = (TextBox) Application.OpenForms["frmMain"].Controls["txtEx"];

// Altera de fato a propriedade
myText.Text = "XYZ";

// Encerra seu formulário Filho
this.Dispose();
```

**Simplificando:**

```
(Application.OpenForms["frmMain"].Controls["txtEx"] as TextBox).Text = "Meu valor";
```