# Método não funciona quando chamado

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho dois formulários:

No `form1` há uma `ListBox` com alguns dados pré-inseridos e um método.
No `form2` há um botão que executa um método no `form1`.

```
//form1
public void limparListBox()
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
}

//form2
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form1 limpar = new form1;
    limpar.limparListBox();
}
```

Por algum motivo que desconheço, ele simplesmente não limpa a `ListBox`.

Quero saber o motivo e como posso resolver este problema.

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como fazer form filho alterar valores no form pai C#?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3035/como-fazer-form-filho-alterar-valores-no-form-pai-c)

Comment: O problema é que você cria uma nova referência da `form1`, ao invés de utilizar a referência para a `form1` que já está criada. Ou seja, você apaga a `ListBox` de uma `form1` que não é a `form1` que você tem a intenção de apagar.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar, wut? Como seria a forma de fazer sem "criar" um novo form1?

Comment: Na verdade, não é que você não criou a `form`, mas, provavelmente, você não está passando a **referência** da `form` que está na tela e, por isso, **parece** não estar executando.
Provavelmente, se você der `limpar.show()`, vai ser apresentada uma outra `form` que tem o `ListBox` limpa.

Comment: Isso funcionaria com um `form` com mais componentes além da `ListBox`? Por exemplo, além da `ListBox`, ter uma `ComboBox` e uma `TextBox`, quero dizer, ele apagaria apenas a `ListBox`?

Comment: Cara, funcionaria com qualquer componente que está na `form`, desde que eles sejam encapsulados com **public**, você pode acessar todos fora da classe principal da `form`. Caso você não queira, basta fazer um método de alteração (como fez com o limpar) e ele vai executar aquele método. (desde que ele seja `public`). De resto o seu problema é exatamente o mesmo [dessa questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3035/como-fazer-form-filho-alterar-valores-no-form-pai-c), como eu escrevi no meu primeiro comentário.

Comment: @FelipeAvelar não entendi muito bem suas colocações... Mas fiz um outro teste, coloquei uma mensagem no método `limparListBox()`, quando eu aciono o método através do botão enquanto a `ListBox` está sem nenhum item, a mensagem aparece, quando não, quando há itens na `ListBox`, a mensagem não aparece.

Answer (score 1):

Isso daqui está incorreto, inclusive no construtor do `form1` que deveria conter a chamada ao método com `()`:

```
//form2
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form1 limpar = new form1(); // em vez de form1;
    limpar.limparListBox();
}
```

O que você faz aqui é chamar o método `limparListBox()` de uma instância de objeto `form1` que acabou de ser criada e provavelmente não é aquela instância que já está sendo exibida na tela e deve ter sido criada em outro momento.

Outro detalhe se refere à falta de padrão para nomes de *classes* e *membros* ao usar **CamelCase** (ou *lowerCamelCase*) que é o padrão utilizado em Java mas não em C#, que utiliza **PascalCase** (ou *UpperCamelCase*). Vou presumir que os tipos foram criados com o Visual Studio e o padrão de case nos nomes de classe foi mantido.

Então, assumindo que temos dois forms (`Form1` e `Form2`) e que o `Form2` é aberto com um botão no `Form1`. O código ficaria assim:

```
//Form1
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Form1 = this; //aqui, vamos criar uma propriedade no Form2 que recebe a referência do Form1: this
    form2.Show();
}

public void LimparListBox() //aqui o método que será chamado no Form2 setado como public
{
    //
}
```

E o código do Form2:

```
//Form2
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form1 Form1 { get; set; } //essa é a propriedade que recebe a referência this do Form1

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // form1 limpar = new form1(); 
        // em vez de criar uma nova instância ... 
        Form1.LimparListBox(); //... usamos aquela passada por referencia
    }
}
```

Comment: Utilizei suas dicas... fiz um outro teste, coloquei uma mensagem no método `limparListBox()`, quando eu aciono o método através do botão enquanto a `ListBox` está sem nenhum item, a mensagem aparece, quando não, quando há itens na `ListBox`, a mensagem não aparece.

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho experiência com C#, mas pelo que entendi o seguinte deve funcionar:

Supondo que estejam em *namespaces* separados, adicione o *namespace* do Form1 no `using` do Form2:

`using Form1;`

Se por acaso estiverem no mesmo *namespace*, o passo acima não é necessário.

E chame a variável pública `form1` assim:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    form1.limpar.limparListBox();
}
```